# Using setMultiples to set indices in a given array to steadily increase

Tags: android, arrays

I need to configure a method using setMultiples(int[] A, int offset),  that will allow me to set the remaining indices of my array (A)  starting at the offset to increasing in multiples of 17. Example (17, 34, 51, etc.)

The follwoing code allows me to fill my array (A) with increasing multiples of 17:

```
for(int i=3; i<500; i++) { values [i] = 17*2; }
```

I cant figure out how to use setMultiples after looking it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this to set the values in the multiples of 17.

```
int[] values = new int[500];
int offset = 3;

setMultiples(values, offset);
```

in setMultiples method

```
private void setMultiples(int[] values, int offset) {
    for(int i=offset; i<500; i++) { 
        values[i] = 17*i;                   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. But how does this work with setMultiples command that I mentioned. That is what Im concerned with sir.

Comment: what is the offset will do ?

Comment: Im sure the offset will continue to increase by multiple of 17. However the setMultiples has to be included in the actual code. That is what im having issues with. "setMultiples HAS TO BE IN THE METHOD".  The logic is perfect, but I dont know how to change it.

Comment: Thats so great, it makes sense. All I had to do was make some adjustments. Thank YOU

Comment: @user3268215 Accept my answer if it really helped you,so that others can refer it.